# Firebase and Electron : firebase.auth(...).onAuthStateChanged is not a function

Tags: firebase, electron, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get firebase working with electron.

Its not really clear if it should be using serviceAccounts or not. is Electron considered to firebase a Server?

When running it I get an error calling `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: firebase.auth(...).onAuthStateChanged is not a function

Thats because I am getting https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth and not the web version of auth().

I am initializing it as I would for the web basically..since that seems what would make most sense as you treat electron as a web app essentially. for instance I dont want to ship a ServiceAccount json with my packaged electron app.

Comment: Right now the Firebase 3.x SDKs are not well-suited to building client applications in Node.js (such as Electron apps, CLIs, or isomorphic web apps). We are working on addressing the issue in a future release, but don't have a specific timeline on when the standard auth methods will be available in Node.js.

Comment: Hello Michael, Thank you for that info..That is a true shame...as I have an app that was going on perfect with SDK 2, and now would be great to continue with firebase since a lot of it was built on top of firebase technology..Is there no workaround it while this is not implemented? I am using only custom authentication I am not actually using the social providers even..

Comment: That is very bad. I just tried to make some unit tests using Mocha, Enzyme and jsdom and got this error. So firebase apps cannot be unit tested in node but only into the browser.. I wanted to omit exactly this thing.. hope that Google will fix this soon